# plot sum of two function

Tags: plotting, functions

I am trying to illustrate sum of functions. I have one function `x*x - 8*x + 7` and another `Log[2*x + 4.5]` I understand that I must add all of coordinates both of these functions.
I use function `Plot` : `Plot[{x*x - 8*x + 7 && Log[2*x + 4.5]}, {x, -10, 10}]`
But it doesn't draw. Can you tell me how it must be.
Thanks.

Comment: need to type 15 char to provide the worlds shortest answer : "+"

Comment: If you want to draw two lines, one for each function, replace `&&` with a comma `,`.  If you want to draw the literal mathematical sum, just replace `&&` with `+`.  But note that the log will not be defined for x < -2.25.

Answer (score 3):

Your first function can have complex values for `x < 0`, so you can define:

```
f1[x_] := Re[x^x + 8 x + 7]; f2[x_] := Log[2 x + 4.4]
```

and then plot the functions together with the sum:

```
Plot[{f1[x], f2[x], f1[x] + f2[x]}, {x, -1, 1}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

But with the range `-10 < x < 10`, you won´t see much left of the y-axis, due to the growth of the first function.

[image: Sum of the functions]